# Install OS in a directory

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

We can have the full filesystem structure of any OS in a directory. To which we can `chroot`, so it will behave as good as native login.

Is there any way to install the an OS onto a partition with the help of chroot ?

e.g. I want to install Ubuntu-14.04 in my `/home/SHW/Ubuntu-14.04` directory. Once installed, I can chroot into it and can do some user-space work

( Installing the OS onto a partition and mounting that at /home/SHW/Ubuntu-14.04 is not what I'm looking for)

EDIT:

Though I have mentioned Ubuntu in original question, but my target OS is developed by third party from scratch. As per the @mattdm, `debootstrap` is useful for ubuntu. But I need almost similar solution to install any OS

Comment: you do not need a full install to chroot. you can use virtual host, export / and mount it via nfs.

Comment: on a second tough, try looking at xen. (I dont provide a full answer because I no longer have a xen to check what should be done).

Comment: If you're looking for "an installer" that lets you install an OS into a directory without the concept of block devices/partitions, have a look at how `gentoo` or `crux` are installed. (substitute `/mnt` with your /home/SHW/gentoo directory in the instructions). Please note that in many situations your commands in the chroot will want access to `/proc` and other parts of the system. If you want ubuntu or something else, it is probably easier to just copy it with `tar` from an installation or running livecd.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! This is what [debootstap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) is for — at least in Debian-derived distributions like Ubuntu. There are great, straightforward instructions for doing (almost) exactly what you're looking for on the Ubuntu wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot. This has some important steps for bind mounting `/proc/`, `/dev/` and `/sys/` which you'll need for the chroot part.

Unfortunately, in the Fedora/RPM-based distro world, we don't have anything quite like that, although a) I think anaconda, the Fedora installer, can actually do this, but there's not good documentation for the process and b) you *can* just `yum install` packages into a chroot, which will work but isn't quite the same as getting a real system installed there. The [Mock](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock) tool does "b" in order to provide a clean environment for package building, and does the bind mounts and everything, and you can actually use it (with `mock shell`) for other things in a pinch.

I say "almost exactly what you're looking for" because a chroot OS won't behave quite like a native install. To get closer, you want to use [*containers*](https://serverfault.com/questions/614223/what-is-linux-containers-after-all/614225#614225), which are basically a system for using Linux kernel features to make that chroot seem more like a full native OS to applications running in it. Right now, the hot topic in this space is [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), a simple tool for managing and launching containers of all sorts. You can make your own base images (starting by using `debootstrap` in a chroot, for example!) or you can launch existing ones from the registry. Try:

```
$ sudo docker run -i -t fedora /bin/bash
```

*even on an Ubuntu system*, and that'll download and put you at a shell prompt inside a Fedora-based container. Or you can use the `ubuntu` base on Fedora or anywhere else — the only requirement is that the host kernel isn't ancient (or, of course, you can just run the same OS in the container as your host OS).

Comment: `debootstrap` is for native Ubuntu only. My target OS is non-standard. I have ISO of it. How can I used the above mentioned methods/tools to achieve the goal.
Once installed, rather invoking any application, I'm more interested to explore their filesystem structure